# How can completely disable Octave plotting

Tags: plot, gnuplot, octave

I am running an Octave script in headless mode using `DISPLAY="" octave --eval myscript;` but still get ASCII plots in the commandline output. This seems to be based on gnuplot (`graphics_toolkit() = gnuplot`). How do I get rid of all console output from the `plot()` command? I still would like the graphics generated by the plots though.

Comment: set the `visible` property of the figure to false

Comment: That works, thanks. Please submit as an answer :)